# my for loop is making every value the last value (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have a user input a value, then define ports based on that value and the following 31 values. These ports should then be stored in an array, but for some reason when I call from the array every value is the last value. (For example, if a user enters 5000, every value in the array ends up being 5031). It's something wrong with storing the actual numbers in the array since if I print the values as they are being created they are all correct.
Excuse the inelegant code, I'm a newbie. Thanks!

```
//enter own ports   
using namespace std;
    cout << "enter a port number between 1000-9999: "; // gets port from user input
    cin >> startingport;


for (int i=0; i<32; i++) // defines 32 ports starting with user input
    {
    sprintf(portchar, "%d", startingport+i);
    cout << "defining port: " << portchar << endl; // gives correct value
    portarray[i] = portchar;
    }

cout << portarray[0] << endl; // gives incorrect value
```

Sorry should have put this before-- I have definitions in another file. I need port to be a character, hence portchar

```
static int startingport;
static char portchar[6];
static char *portarray[32];
```

Comment: Where is your declaration for `portarray`?

Comment: You don't change the value of portchar anywhere

Comment: Use `std::string`, not pointers. You're storing the same pointer each time, just overwriting the string it points to.

Comment: @Atuos Yes he does (sprintf)

Comment: @deviantfan: That writes to the array it points to, but doesn't change the pointer. The same pointer is stored each time, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to echo Mike Seymour's comment that you should be using `std::string`s and a container, not `char*` and `*char[]`. The higher level abstractions help mitigate a lot of the common issues related to pointer management and arithmetic.

That said, this is a good teachable moment.

#### What went wrong

Let's begin by telling ourselves that a pointer (`*`) is nothing more than an address. Just like how I live at 555 First St, all objects in memory have an address. If I move out of my address and someone else moves in, when someone asks who lives at 555 First St, the answer at that moment will be whoever moved in, *not* me.

If pointers are just addresses, then what is an array of pointers? Well, it's just a list of addresses! Imagine a list with empty slots that can hold 32 addresses. This is what `portarray` is.

So what does your loop do? Well there are three basic operations:

```
sprintf(portchar, "%d", startingport+i);
```

This is equivalent to someone moving into the address `portchar`. The address is still the same, there's just something new in there now.

```
cout << "defining port: " << portchar << endl;
```

This is the same as asking who lives at that address. Of course, you know what this is, it's just `startingport+1` since `startingport+1` just moved in!

Finally:

```
portarray[i] = portchar;
```

Pay close attention to this. This says to copy down the address `portchar` into your list of addresses. Imagine you had a piece of paper and you wrote down `"0: 555 First St"`. This is *not* copying down who *lives* at that address, but the address itself. The next iteration of this loop, when it comes time to write down the address again, we'd write `"1: 555 First St"`, same as before.

So at the end of your loop, you'll have this nice list of addresses, and all of the addresses are exactly the same, because of course you never actually *changed the address* in your loop.

#### What can you do about it (without using `std::string`)

If you're willing to manually manage the memory pointed to by `portarray`, you can fix your issues using heap allocated memory. This is necessary because you need `32` unique addresses that you can put into `portarray`. Your statically allocated `portchar` gives you one address which is insufficiently.

```
// Assuming you've removed your portchar declaration
for (int i=0; i<32; i++) // defines 32 ports starting with user input
{
    portarray[i] = new char[6]; // This dynamically allocates memory
    sprintf(portarray[i], "%d", startingport+i);
    cout << "defining port: " << portarray[i] << endl; // gives correct value
}

cout << portarray[0] << endl; // gives correct value
```

To free up the memory later, you have to do:

```
for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
    delete[] portarray[i];
}
```

It looks messy, and that's because it is. As others have suggested, you can avoid this minefield by using `std::string` and containers. If your code is amenable to those abstractions, I highly recommend using them.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I am actually locked into defining the final array as char because of some constraints later in the code (this is someone else's code that I'm adding the user input part to, and to change the type throughout would be a lot of work). 

Will it work to make portchar a std::string and then pull from it for portarray?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution that doesn't use `std::string`. The problem with using `std::string` with your existing code is that you need to allocate it dynamically to keep it alive beyond the scope of your for loop iterations. But for everything that you keep alive, you have to kill later on. Since you're already keeping track of character pointers, it makes more sense to use dynamically allocated character pointers than it does to use `std::string`s.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!! I'm working off of some pretty crappy old code with a lot of constraints. Your solution above almost works-- it instead defines everything as startingport+1. But I got it to work if I added a line: _startingport=startingport+1;_

Comment: It looks like you transcribed it as `startingpoint+1` when it should be `startingpoint+i`.

Comment: haha yep, I meant if I added the line startingpoint+i it works. I'm getting a segmentation error now when everything runs through though-- is this related to perhaps not clearing the memory at the appropriate time?

Comment: If you get rid of the delete statement and run through the program just fine, it means the delete happens too early. There's probably a pointer that points to that memory location somewhere in your program.

Comment: Yeah tried that, still getting the fault. Thought maybe it was because I wasn't clearing it, but that doesn't make sense. Probably just another error left behind for me to clean up in this old code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They will be pointing to the same underlying value, as you repeatedly use 'portchar' to print to and it happens to be a static char.

portarray[0]  -> 
portarray[1]  ->
...
portarray[2]  ->
   all pointing to 'portchar'

All of them are pointing to the shared char array. You need to fix a few things:

1. Since portarray is declared as an array of pointers, you would need individual buffers to point to.
2. Change portarray to be declared as an array of std::string. You would get a copy. Thus, you will have distinct values.
3. Keep portarray as an array of pointers, but, allocate a new portchar for each iteration of the loop and store these pointers.

_3 is not great, as you would have to manage the memory yourself.

_2 is better, along with using a std::vector<> for portarray.

_1 is generating copies of strings, which you need to decide if you want to pay that cost.

Comment: Thanks! I need to have portarray as type char for use further down in the code. Would that be incompatible with option 2?

Comment: No, what I am suggesting is "std::string portarray[NUM_REQUIRED]" having said that, such a hardcoded number based approach is not generally recommended. Instead, you should use std::vector<std::string> portarray. And, you can do portarray.push_back(portchar) for every new element.